# Обязан ли автор форка-дистрибутива Ubuntu указывать авторов оригинального дистрибутива?

Tags: ubuntu

Если дистрибутив является форком Ubuntu, где прописана обязанность разработчика форка указать, что он основан на Ubuntu?
Ознакомившись с лицензией, GPL3, а также с юридической информацией на сайте Ubuntu, у меня сложилось впечатление, что указывать авторов является скорее хорошей традицией, чем обязанностью. Помогите найти в тексте лицензий, где прописана эта обязанность. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Учитывая тот факт, что суды по поводу нарушения GPL вещь крайне редкая в общемировой практике, не вижу смысла подходить буквоедски. Достаточно исполнить дух лицензии. Я бы ограничился указанием "основано на Ubuntu" в общей информации о дистрибутиве

Answer (score 1):

Из общих соображений: у дистрибутива Линукс нет авторов.

Дистрибутив - это инсталлятор, загрузчик, ядро, система управления пакетами, сами пакеты, файлы настроек, прочие ресурсы (картинки, шрифты, аудио-видео файлы). У всех этих сущностей свои авторы и свои лицензии. Соответственно, когда вы создаёте свой клон дистрибутива, вам нужно разбираться с каждой лицензией.

Скажем, инсталлятор Убунты [лицензирован по GPL-3.0](https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-desktop-provision/blob/main/LICENSE).

В интернетах давно спорят, требует ли GPL указывать имена исходных авторов, или нет. Мнения расходятся, могу добавить ещё одно:

- лицензия требует указания, что данная работа является производной, и модифицирована вами,
- [FAQ по GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#WhyDoesTheGPLPermitUsersToPublishTheirModifiedVersions) поясняет, что это делается для защиты оригинальных авторов - если вдруг что навернётся, это будет урон по репутации автора модификации, а не изначальных авторов.
- ИМХО, самый простой способ показать объем модификации, это пометить свои изменения именем разработчика модификации, и сохранить отсылки к предыдущим авторам/модификаторам.

Поэтому я всегда сохраняю ссылки на предыдущих авторов, даже если сильно переделываю код.

Что же касается конкретно Убунты, то на первых страницах их сайта и вики я не нашел упоминаний Debian. Пришлось пользоваться поиском, чтобы узнать, что [Ubuntu builds on the Debian architecture and infrastructure and collaborates widely with Debian developers](https://ubuntu.com/community/governance/debian). [В самом первом публичном релизе (4.10)](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2004-October/000003.html) они упомянули Debian в самом начале, но уже Убунту 5.10 [вышла без ссылок на прародителя](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2005-October/000038.html).

ИМХО, можете последовать их примеру и в первых релизах ссылаться на Убунту, а когда наберёте базу пользователей, забыть про корни. Разве что упомянуть где-нибудь на задворка сайта проекта, что ваш дистрибутив основан на Убунте, но Убунтой не является.